# Vb.net File.ReadAllLines Method

Tags: vb.net

I've created an application with timer that is to change the text of a label based on the contents of my file.

My text file:

```
00:00:05 "Some Text"    
00:00:10 "Some Text"     
00:00:25 "Some Text"
```

Just like a subtitle file, my form will change the label text at each of the timestamps.

I use this code to read the text file:

```
Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile)
Dim line1() As String = Lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Split
Dim line2() As String = Lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Split
Dim line3() As String = Lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2).Split
```

But it doesn't work on if the file has more than 3 lines.

What the solution for this?

Comment: Just don't use labels.  Use ListBox or ListView instead.

Comment: Are you familiar with loops and collections/arrays?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more readable. Please let me know if I've missed anything important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a loop instead of hard-coding 0, 1, and 2. To stay with your variable names:

```
Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile)
For Each line In Lines
  Dim splittedLine() As String = line.Split
  'whatever you do with the splitted line
Next
```

Comment: yep... also as I can already imagine the confusion, the vb.net comment syntax is `'whatever you do with the splitted line`

Answer (score 0):

I would go about doing it like this:

```
Dim now = DateTime.Now

Dim data = _
( _
    From line in File.ReadLines(MyFile) _
    Let timestamp = now.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(line.Substring(0, 8))) _
    Let text = String.Join(" ", line.Split().Skip(1)) _
    Select New With { .TimeStamp = timestamp, .Text = text } _
).ToArray()
```

From my sample data I then get these results:

[image: results]

As you can see, the array contains the actual time to display the text and the text itself. It should be fairly easy now to use the timer to compare the current time with the next time stamp and move an index to keep track of the current line to display.